# .htaccess RewriteRule and RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm struggling with this issue for a couple of hours already.
Basically I have the new version of my website in

```
var/www/mynewsite/public
```

I have a symlink in my www/ folder that points like this

```
www/v2_legacy -> /d1/v2_legacy/
```

Now, I need anyone who accesses **www.mysite.com** to be redirected to **www.mysite.com/mynewsite/public/**

But I also need to keep some old links alive, thus, accessing **www.mysite.com/clients/whatever** should redirect the users to **www.mysite.com/v2_legacy/clients/whatever**. Besides the "clients" folder I will have also two others in there.

This is my .htaccess that is located in the www/ folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^clients/(.*)$ v2_legacy/clients/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^v2_legacy/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mynewsite/public/$1 [L]
```

I already tried so many variants of this file but still cant get an appropiate behaviour.

Using the above htaccess file, accessing www.mysite.com will redirect correctly, but accessing www.mysite.com/clients/somestuff will not. However, if I comment out the last RewriteCond and RewriteRule, accessing www.mysite.com/clients/somestuff will work correctly but, accessing www.mysite.com, obviously, will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable always starts with a slash. Matching it against `^something` will thus always be false (and negating that makes it always true). Besides that you need to prevent an infinite loop from happening, as `^(.*)$` matches `mynewsite/public/...` too.

You would end up with something along the lines of:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^clients/(.*)$ v2_legacy/clients/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(v2_legacy|mynewsite)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mynewsite/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much, I did not know about the slash. It works finally.